# SweetAlert2: Unexpected type of html! Expected "string", got object

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am trying to have a [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) dialog showing two buttons, with the following code snippet:

```
swal('Some text', {
  buttons: {
    buttonA: {
      text: 'Some text',
      value: 'buttonA',
      className: 'some-class'
    },
    buttonB: {
      text: 'Some other text',
      value: 'buttonB',
      className: 'some-class'
    }
  },
  buttonsStyling: false
}).then((result) => {
  switch (result) {
    case 'buttonA':
      // Do something
      break;
    default:
      // Do something else
  }
})
```

But I get the following error message:

> SweetAlert2: Unexpected type of html! Expected "string", got object

Also, the dialog only shows one "OK" button

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/5jLv12ed/2/, its working perfectly.

Maybe some other javascript is overlapping in your code.

Comment: This one https://jsfiddle.net/c1guw4f8/5/ shows the problem but I can't figure out the difference with the one you provided

Comment: I have used the latest ver that is the difference.

Comment: Apparently this feature was removed in SweetAlert2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed [SweetAlert2](http://sweetalert2.github.io) but using the API of [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/). Those two are different plugins with different APIs nowadays.

Use SweetAlert2's API to get the desired result:

```js
swal({
  title: 'Hello world!',
  confirmButtonText: 'Some text',
  cancelButtonText: 'Some other text',
  confirmButtonClass: 'some-class',
  cancelButtonClass: 'some-other-class',
  showCancelButton: true
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.value) {
    console.log('button A pressed')
  } else {
    console.log('button B pressed')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it's a shame that we can't get more then two buttons on a SweetAlert2 dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Use the latest `sweetalert`

Just Replace your `sweetalert` script file with this :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

[here](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) is the documentation